# PyQt. How to insert a widget in a QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget, qtableview

There is a table:

```
tab=QTableView()
sti=QStandardItemModel(parent=None)
sti.appendRow([QStandardItem(str(1)),QStandardItem(str(2)),QStandardItem(str(3)),QStandardItem(str(4))])
tab.setModel(sti)
tab.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
```

There is a button:

```
btn=QPushButton('Press', self)
btn.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
```

Task: How can I insert button btn in the table cell insert of QStandardItem(str(4))? There is a method .setCellWidget() of class QTableWidget for it, but I inherited from QTableView. If I'll use QTableWidget I'll can't use private method .setModel()

Comment: @eyllanesc It has matter? I want simply add a button in a table even if it will has no action

Comment: @eyllanesc in general this button launch a big function, that use index of table cell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be able to insert a widget you must use the [`setIndexWidget()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) method where the `QModelIndex()` associated to the cell must be passed as the first parameter, considering that the indexes of the row and column start from 0, for the item with text equal to `str(4)` its coordinate is `0, 3`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")
    tab = QTableView()
    sti = QStandardItemModel()
    sti.appendRow([QStandardItem(str(i)) for i in range(4)])
    tab.setModel(sti)
    tab.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    tab.setIndexWidget(sti.index(0, 3), QPushButton("button"))
    tab.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

if you have the `QStandardItem()` you can also access the `QModelIndex` through the [`indexFromItem()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#indexFromItem) method